# Unable to print all rows of DB to Django template

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am very new with Django and really need some help.

So, I am making the basic to-do application and have created the database, added some sample data (which I can see through the admin interface) and now I need to print each line to the screen.

I have the below and I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't print.

Can anyone advise?

**MODELS**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Todo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**VIEWS**

```
from .models import Todo
def todo(request):
    todo_list = Todo.objects.all()
    context = {'todo_list' : todo_list}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

**HOME.HTML**

```
<ul>
        {% for todo in todo_list %}
        {{todo_list}}
        <li>{{ todo.text }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**URLS**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from netshock import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('login/', views.login_user, name='login'),
    url('logout/', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
```

]

**SETTINGS**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/home/django/django_project/netshock/templates/authenticate'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: which url you hit?

Comment: I go to my home.html to try and view it

Comment: I say something like `127.0.0.1/todo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `urls.py` add:

```
url(r'todo/^$', views.todo, name='todo'),
```

keep your `home.html` under your app `todo/templates`(asume that **Todo** model is under `todo` app)
the hit the url
http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/